# How to print each block with input pattern from keyboard?

Tags: bash, shell

Example file:

```
TCP  192.168.56.224:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.112:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.113:80            Route   1      0          0
TCP  192.168.56.225:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.109:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.110:80            Route   1      0          0
TCP  192.168.56.226:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.3:80              Route   1      0          0
UDP  192.168.56.224:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.112:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.113:80            Route   1      0          0
UDP  192.168.56.225:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.109:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.110:80            Route   1      0          0
UDP  192.168.56.226:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.3:80              Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.120:80            Route   1      0          0
```

I want to print the corresponding TCP and UDP blocks according to the pattern entered from the keyboard and using awk or sed command.

Example: input 192.168.56.110:80 value, then I want to print the result is:

```
TCP  192.168.56.225:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.109:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.110:80            Route   1      0          0
UDP  192.168.56.225:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.109:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.110:80            Route   1      0          0
```

Please help me.

Comment: Please try to add your efforts which you have tried to solve this in your question too, as we all are here to learn.

Comment: Sorry, How I can try to add my effort ? 
I new member, so I don't know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach using `gnu awk`:

```
awk -v RS='(^|\n)(TC|UD)P[[:blank:]]' -v ip='192.168.56.110:80' 'index($0, ip) {
print RT $0}' file
```

```
TCP  192.168.56.225:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.109:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.110:80            Route   1      0          0

UDP  192.168.56.225:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.109:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.110:80            Route   1      0          0
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
cat script.ksh
echo "Please enter the ip address which you want to print:"
read value

awk -v val="$value" '/^TCP/||/^UDP/{value=""}!flag{value=value?value ORS $0:$0} $0 ~ val{flag=1} flag{print value;value=flag=""}'  Input_file
```

It will ask person who runs the script an IP to enter and when user enters it, it will then look that into Input_file.

Comment: Thank you. But, I want to print extra values below in the results I want to display:
TCP 192.168.56.225:80 rr and UDP 192.168.56.225:80 rr
Can you help me?

Comment: gsysadmin@ksw-kanshilvs-2001:~/folder$ ./script.sh
Please enter the ip address which you want to print:
192.168.56.110:80
  -> 192.168.56.110:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.110:80            Route   1      0          0
But, I want to print the follow: 
TCP  192.168.56.225:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.109:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.110:80            Route   1      0          0
UDP  192.168.56.225:80 rr
  -> 192.168.56.109:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.110:80            Route   1      0          0

Comment: I want to print the follow:
 **TCP  192.168.56.225:80 rr**
  -> 192.168.56.109:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.110:80            Route   1      0          0 
**UDP  192.168.56.225:80 rr**
  -> 192.168.56.109:80            Route   1      0          0
  -> 192.168.56.110:80            Route   1      0          0

Comment: Thank you so much.
I think @anubhava have helped me.

Comment: @donald.sys, you could give upvote to people for thanking them and try to select any of the best answer as correct answer too, keep learning, cheers.

Comment: Yes. Best friend :)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: This is good but slight problem is that text `192.168.56.110:80` is available 2 lines after `TCP` or `UDP` and that's when you start printing. Due to that reason it is missing 2 lines in output.

Comment: @anubhava, thank you sir I have changed it now as per OP's requirement.

Comment: @donald.sys, check my edited solution now, it should help you now.